macOS changes input to headphones without a mic
I have HAYLOU S35 ANC, which are bluetooth headphones without a microphone. I used it well before, however yesterday I used another mic with my laptop, a professional one, which I connected through a sound card, and I needed manually change input in the settings. My headphones were also connected (bluetooth). After that, when I pair my headphones with the laptop, macOS automatically sets Audio input to the headset, even though it doesn't have a mic :( so now every time I pair I have to manually set audio input back to the laptop mic, otherwise the sound is awful.
I also recently discovered that when I pair with my iPhone, I can't record audio, like the iPhone is also expecting the audio input to go through the headset. It happened several days before I the macOS bug happened, however it looks connected.
I'm trying to figure out whether it's macOS / iOS bug, or the headphones. But in any case,
the main question: is there a way to force macOS to use specific audio input for a specific audio device, without using a third-party software? In example, if HAYLOU headset is connected, then set Audio output to HAYLOU, and Audio input to MacBook.
MacBook Air M1 2020, macOS Sonoma 14.1.1
Thank you.

You can try to create a Bluetooth device profile for your HAYLOU headset in macOS to remember these settings.
Go to System Preferences > Bluetooth, right-click on your HAYLOU headset, and select "Add to Favorites".
This may help..

Thank you for your reply. There's no option "Add to Favorites" when right-clicking on a Bluetooth device, only "Rename / Disconnect / Forget"
